# Copying a work schedule from a website and importing it to google calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, schedule

I am looking to write a script that would copy schedule information from a website and import it to my google schedule. I have started to learn python to solve this problem,however, I am seeing so many approaches most of which confuse me. Could I get a recommendation to a beginner friendly a approach to this problem. Thanks for any help :)

I have been working through the book "automate the....with python" and I saw an example with selenium that simulates user clicks and so on, however, I'm not sure if this is the approach I'm looking for. Maybe a simpler request based approach might be more suitable.

edit:
I was able to retrieve the data i wanted using the request and BeautifulSoup libraries. The data i'm getting so far is :

(, , , , , , )

I think now i need to extract each date and corresponding hours and then create a corresponding event on my calendar through google calendar API. Once again any help is greatly appreciated.

My code so far:

```
#program that gets data from McDonalds Schedule website
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36'
}
login_data = {
    'localeCode':'',
    'uType':'',
    'switchUserID':'',
    'browserTimeZoneOffset': '-60',
    'txtUserID': '',
    'txtPassword': ''
    }

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://psschedule.reflexisinc.co.uk/wfmmcdirlprd/LoginSubmit.jsp"
    r = s.get(url,headers=headers)
    r = s.post(url, data = login_data, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')

table = soup.find_all('input', id=re.compile("^daydet_\d+"))
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could scrape the website with node.js and thus retrieve the schedule data. You can then use a Google Calendar API node module to create events inside your own calendar.